# Cannot start eventlog service

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, windows-event-log

On a windows 2k8R2 DC box the eventlog service wont start.  When i try to start the service the machine returns: "Windows could not start the Windows Event Log service on Local Computer.  Error 13: The data is invalid."

event viewer wont open either.

obviously, i dont have an event log for this error.

ive already tried clearing the event logs.  that didnt do anything.

the other DC isnt experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the event logs, %SystemRoot%\system32\config*.evt. Try to restart the service if it won't reboot. The system will automatically generate new, clear logs.

Comment: i restored from backup for other reasons before trying this, but had to perform a similar set of tasks to get the security log to work again.  pretty sure this would have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had some dodgy folders under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\`.

This was after some dev had added some logs and made a bubu.
Deleted the folders and all was good!